# How to OCR PDF files with Old German Gothic (Fraktur) text?

Tags: mac, adobe-acrobat, ocr, german

I have been successfully using Adobe Acrobat X to OCR many scanned documents which I use for my research. However I have begun studying old German documents which use the [Fraktur script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur_%28script%29), also known as Gothic. SuperUser won't let me post an image of it, but you can find examples of what it looks like in the Wikipedia article (linked above).

I have read about special programs which OCR the text, such as [ABBY FineReader für Fraktur](http://www.frakturschrift.com/), but first it works on Windows (and I use a Mac), and second I'd like to find a Fraktur plugin for Acrobat to fit into my already-existing workflow. **Are there any Fraktur OCR plugins for Acrobat? Generally, where should one look for Acrobat OCR plugins?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about OCR plugins for Acrobat. However, it looks like [ocropus](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/) has support for Fraktur text and someone was kind enough to build a OS X version with a simple gui called [TakOCR](http://stuporglue.org/takocr/).

edit: see the Stack Overflow question [Fraktur recognition with OCRopus/Tesseract on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867632/fraktur-recognition-with-ocropus-tesseract-on-linux)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in this direction. However it appears that these applications only output text files, rather than making the PDF searchable itself.

Comment: ABBYY Finereader claims to be able to read gothic fonts.